# python opencv VideoWriter: OpenCV: Frame size does not match video size

Tags: python, opencv, video

I have a series of images and I want the opencv could read all the images and create a video for the first image to the last. The images just called 1,2,3,4....151.

```
import cv2

img=[]
for i in range(0,151):
    img.append(cv2.imread(str(i)+'.png'))

height,width,layers=img[1].shape
video=cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi',-1,1,(width,height))

for j in range(0,151):
    video.write(img[j])


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

and the following error was raised:

```
OpenCV: Frame size does not match video size
```

after that a video was created but just a few images were actually used to produce the video.

where is incorrect?

Comment: Try with `video=cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi',-1,1,(height, width))`

Comment: it still doesn't work but the error is now  mMovieWriter.status: 3. Error: Cannot Save

Comment: Solution is given here:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43448456/how-to-store-webcam-video-with-opencv-in-python/43450241)

Answer (score 0):

For "mMovieWriter.status: 3. Error: Cannot Save", you can try removing the video.avi file created during your tests.